# Eclipse RCP refresh not visible EditorReference / IEditorPart

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, refresh, rcp, invisible

[Eclipse RCP components](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NUx6w.png)
Regarding atached image:
Is it possible to refresh the content of a Not Visible EditorReference without activate it?
PS: for me Not Visible EditorReference are tabs under >>4.

Comment: It doesn't matter if something is visible or not as far as refreshing is concerned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not needed anymore. I will close this post.